# Error Switch-Case - Programming C - Beginner

Tags: c

I am in my 1st semester of College and having trouble to solve a computation in my class. Although I have done a lot of research and tried many ways, I still cannot get the correct result. I hope someone can help me out as this is my 1st time in Stackoverflow. I am using Code Block btw.

Requirements:

1. First, user is prompted to enter two capacitance values representing capacitors C1 and C2.
2. The program then displays the following menu:

   - Calculate and display the total capacitance (CT)
   - Calculate and display the voltage drops for each resistor (VC1, VC2)
   - Calculate and display the electrical charge (QT) User is asked to enter 1, 2, or 3 to select one of three options displayed on the screen.
3. For the following, you must use the switch statement. - If option 1, 2, or 3 is entered, total capacitance, voltage drops, or electrical charge is calculated using formulas below:

V = 12 C = (C1*C2) / (C1+C2)

V = V1 + V2 where V1 = V*(C/C1) and V2=V*(C/C1)

Q = Q1 + Q1.

4. If any character other than 1, 2, or 3 is entered, the program will display an error message: - This is not a valid option!

Here is my Code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main (){
    char choice;
    float c1,c2,ct;
    ct =(c1 * c2) / (c1+c2);
    printf("Please enter the capacitance value of c1: ");
    scanf("%f", &c1);
    printf("\nPlease enter the capacitance value of c2: ");
    scanf("%f", &c2);

    printf("\nPlease enter 1 if you need total capacitance");
    printf("\nPlease enter 2 if you need voltage of each resistor");
    printf("\nPlease enter 3 if you need electrical charge \n");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
        printf("\nThe total capacitance is %.2f", ct);
        case 2:
        printf("\nThe Voltage drop V1 is %.2f and V2 is %.2f", 12*(ct/c1), 12*(ct/c2));
        case 3:
        printf("\nThe electrical charge is Q %.2f", 12 * ct );

        default:
        printf("\nInvalid weekday number.");
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: @xing thanks a lot! it worked now! but still 1 thing is that after I run and input 2 value of c1, c2. If i enter 1 to choose the first choice to see "total capacitance", all result of other choices also appear on screen (not only the first choice appear as expected). It happens the same when I enter 2, it will show the result of second, third and even default.

Comment: @Matthew You'll want `break` statements, see my answer below

Comment: @xing and Alex many thanks! it worked perfectly now! i am just curious, what if i wanna keep the window open after running program first time and allow users to re-enter other values to run program again and again, and the window will only be closed when user enter specific key like "close". Could you please help me with the code for that or just give me an idea i will do the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @xing says in the comments, you'll want to use single quotes as in `case '1':` in your switch statement. In C, `1` is an integer literal and `'1'` is a character literal. The single quotes basically cause C to convert the character to its ASCII value, so that will match what you get back from `scanf` with `%c`. However, because chars in C are basically 1-byte integers, your compiler may not complain if you tell it (via the `case` statement) to compare a char and an integer.

You'll probably also want a `break;` statement at the end of each `case`, to break out of the `switch` without executing the next `case`s.